# Phaser: How to detect collisoin between Phaser.Geom.Line and Phaser.Geom.Point?

Tags: collision-detection, game-engine, phaser-framework

I'm planning to create a basic game where the point moves using Phaser.Geom.Point and that point should be bounded by lines using Phaser.Geom.Line.  How do you detect when there is a collision between Phaser.Geom.Point and Phaser.Geom.Line ????

Comment: Have you considered using Arcade Physics bodies instead of Geom objects?

Comment: No...can you draw lines and circles and points with Arcade Physics bodies?

Comment: No, but you can easily create lines, circles and points as images in any number of free drawing tools like Paint and attach the physics bodies to these images.